# RabbitMQ consumer perfomance - prefetch vs concurency

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I have a Go application processing events from a single RabbitMQ queue. I use the [`github.com/streadway/amqp`](https://github.com/streadway/amqp) RabbitMQ Client Library.

The Go application processes every message in ~2-3 seconds. It's possible to process ~1000 or even more messages in parallel, if I feed them from memory.
But, unfortunately, RabbitMQ performance is worse.
So, I want to consume messages from queue faster.

So, the question is: how to consume messages in most effective manner using `github.com/streadway/amqp`?

As far as I understand, there are two approaches:

1. set high prefetch

   https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.Qos.

   Use single consumer goroutine

   Example code:

```golang
conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
defer conn.Close()

ch, err := conn.Channel()
failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
defer ch.Close()

ch.Qos(
        10000,           // prefetch count
        0,               // prefetch size
        false,           // global
    )

msgs, err := ch.Consume(
  q.Name, // queue
  "",     // consumer
  false,  // NO auto-ack
  false,  // exclusive
  false,  // no-local
  false,  // no-wait
  nil,    // args
)

for d := range msgs {
  log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
  err:= processMessage(d)
  if err != nil {
      log.Printf("%s : while consuming task", err)
      d.Nack(false, true)
  } else {
      d.Ack(false)
  }
  continue // consume other messages
}
```

But DO the `processMessage` will be called here in parallel?

2. spawn many channels and use multiple consumers

```golang
conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
defer conn.Close()
var i = 0
for i = 0; i<=100; i++ {
  go func(){
      ch, err := conn.Channel()
      failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
      defer ch.Close()

      ch.Qos(
            10,           // prefetch count
            0,               // prefetch size
            false,           // global
    )

      msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        q.Name, // queue
        "",     // consumer
        false,  // NO auto-ack
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-local
        false,  // no-wait
        nil,    // args
      )

      for d := range msgs {
        log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
        err:= processMessage(d)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("%s : while consuming task", err)
            d.Nack(false, true)
        } else {
            d.Ack(false)
        }
        continue // consume other messages
      }
  }()
}
```

But is this a RAM friendly approach? Isn't spawning a new channel for each worker is quite dramatic for RabbitMQ?

So, question is, which variant is better? Better performance, better memory usage, etc.

So, what is the optimal usage of RabbitMQ here?

Update: currently, I encountered a case when my worker consumes all RAM on VPS, and is OOM-killed. I used second approach for it. So, better in my case is ability to keep my worker without OOM killing after few minutes of work.

Update 2: `nack` when worker failed to process message, and `ack` when worker processed message is very important. All messages has to be processed (its customers analytics), but sometimes worker cannot process it, so it have to `nack` message to pass it to other workers (currently, some 3rd party api used to process messages sometimes simply returns 503 status code, in this case message should be passed to other worker or retried).
SO, using `auto-ack` is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Define "better". I could argue that writing simple code is much more efficient than writing complex code, as it saves developer time (which is expensive). Or that using a lot of memory is actually better than to have it idle around unused. Aside from that, I'd go for the former code variant and use [a fan out pattern](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) downstream.

Comment: i updated question - better for me is - code uses less ram, and it can process more messages on the same sime. Fan out pattern seems not working when i tried to implement it, since `d` - amqp messages, `ack` and `nack` seems to be not thread safe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose each `processMessage()` run in a new goroutine.

> Which variant is better?

I prefer the first one, because open/close channel is a little bit expensive (2 + 2 TCP packets). I think your OOM problem is not related to too many gorutine, gorutine is very light, just cost about 5KB. So the problem is probably caused by your `processMessage()`.

I think the `github.com/streadway/amqp` channel consume operation is [thread/gorutine-safe](https://github.com/streadway/amqp/pull/321), so it is safe to share channel between goruntine if you just do some consume operation.